# SOQL query to exclude the deleted file from feeditem

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I'm trying to display the feeditems with attachments in VF page.

I'm trying to query the Feeditem using the following query.

```
SELECT id, ContentFileName, ContentSize, CreatedDate FROM FeedItem WHERE Type = 'ContentPost' AND ParentId ='Sobject Id'
```

I'm getting the records, no issue.
but when I delete the file from the content Document, the post still shows in my Sobject Feeds but it says "file is no longer available".
I need to exclude the records from the feeditem whose attachment file is not available in feeditem
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't filter ContentFileName, ContentSize, RelatedRecordId in query call according to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm), but you can skip those files by checking their content size in apex, for e.g

```
if(ContentSize!=Null && ContentSize > 0)
   mylist.add(feedItem);
```